# Prove that the exponential of matrix is well defined

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

We just saw today the concept of the exponential of a matrix. Let $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ a matrix. How can I prove that $$e^A:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}$$ is well defined ?

**What I've done so far**

- *Case 1:* If $D$ is diagonal, then $$(e^{D})_{ij}=\begin{cases}e^{d_i}&i=j\\0&otherwise\end{cases}.$$
  Therefore, it's well defined (i.e. that $e^1\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$).
- *Case 2:* If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A=\Lambda D\Lambda ^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $\Lambda $ and some diagonal matrix $D$. Then I could prove that $e^A=\Lambda e^D\Lambda ^{-1}$, and thus, $e^A$ is well defined.
- *Case 3:* If $A$ is triangular, then $A=D+N$ for some diagonal matrix $D$ and some nilpotent matrix $N$. Since $A^k=D^k$ for all $k\geq n$, we are in the same case than the Case 1.
- *Case 4:* If $A$ is trigonalizable, combining the Cases 2 and 3 gives the wished result.

**Question** How can I do in the case where $A$ is not trigonalisable ?

Comment: Do you know the power series expansion of $e^x$?

Comment: Yes of course... $e^A:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}$... but why for $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ not trigonalizable, $e^A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ ? @TedShifrin

Comment: Every matrix admits a Jordan form.

Comment: Although you can complete your proof by means of @KBS hint, I would recommend to use the estimate $\Vert A^k \Vert \leq \Vert A \Vert^k$ to show that the series converges absolutely.